# html5: how to markup proper names and common names?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

```
<p>...the favourite color of Purple is purple...</p>
```

the first "Purple" is a name of a company, the second one is a color name,

how should I markup this according to html5 spec?

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you ever seen it anywhere before?

Comment: only in a parallel universe where everything is called like is called everything

Comment: You'll need supernatural powers to do this. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of options:

1. Leave it as is, HTML isn't really concerned with semantics which aren't about describing document structure (paragraphs, headings, lists etc.).  If you do want to express more detailed document or application semantics look at [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/).
2. If it's important for you to distinguish between the two uses of the word purple as part of your website or app then use the `class` attribute or [`data-*` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)
3. If the words have canonical machine readable forms and you want the values to be parsed by a computer somehow, use [the `data` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element).
4. If distinguishing between the two uses is important to users or systems consuming your site content, use the semantic extensibility feature of HTML5: [Microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#microdata).  (If you're using the XML dialect of HTML, see also: [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/))
5. Combine any of the above approaches according to your immediate needs.

To decide between the approaches you should ask yourself:

- For what purpose do I need to extend the semantic vocabulary of HTML?
- Is it for my own uses, or am I trying to publish information to be used by others?
- If I'm publishing for others, what shared vocabulary am I going to use?

Code examples:

**Class attributes**

What they're for is adding additional information to your markup, remember the `class` attribute is in the HTML spec, *not* the CSS spec:

```
<p>...the favourite color of <span class="company">Purple</span>
  is <span class="color">purple</span>...</p>
```

Having said that, of course, the obvious thing to do once you have things marked up in this way is provide in page tools to do things like 'highlight all companies'.  People have used the `class` attribute as the basis for a general purpose semantic extension mechanism however, for this approach taken to the extreme see [microformats](http://microformats.org/).

**Data attributes**

The `data-*` attributes are to allow you to add custom attributes to your markup for processing with scripts in a way which guarantees you won't accidentally use a custom attribute which then gets used in a future version of HTML:

```
<p>...the favourite color of <span data-typeofthing="company">Purple</span>
  is <span data-typeofthing="color">purple</span>...</p>
```

It's up to scripts on your page to do something useful with the `data-*` attributes, browsers and other web clients will ignore them.

**Custom data elements**

Data elements are for things that have an imprecise natural language expression but also a precise machine readable expression.  Assuming that the company can be uniquely identified by a ticker symbol and RGB will do for the colour:

```
<p>...the favourite color of <data value="purp">Purple</data>
  is <data value="rgb(128,0,128)">purple</data>...</p>
```

Browsers probably won't do anything special with the `data` element.  It's most likely you'll use `data` elements in concert with microformats, RDFa or Microdata.

**Microdata**

Using the [Organization schema](http://schema.org/Organization):

```
<p>...the favourite color of 
  <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <span itemprop="name">Purple</span>
  </span>
is purple...</p>
```

There isn't anything for colours that I'm aware of, but you could always publish your own schema for that if it's important to you.  This approach only really benefits anyone if there is a shared vocabulary of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

### Which element?

The first task would be to decide which element should be used to enclose the "entities" (company name and color name). Most probably you want to use `span` here. If in doubt, use `span`. There are some cases (depends on content) where other elements could be used:

- the **[`b` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-b-element.html#the-b-element)** might be used if the entity is some kind of keyword ("a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood")
- if the entity is the title of a work (book, film, song etc.), the **[`cite` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-cite-element.html#the-cite-element)** should be used.
- the **[`dfn` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dfn-element.html#the-dfn-element)** might be used if the entities are defined in the same paragraph or in the nearest ancestor sectioning element
- in some cases the **[`i` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-i-element.html#the-i-element)** could be appropriate

If the term is an abbreviation/acronym, use the **[`abbr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-abbr-element.html#the-abbr-element)** (*instead* of `span` resp. in *addition to* `b`/`dfn`/`i`).

A good idea might be to use the **[`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element)** to link the entity name to a relevant webpage. The `rel` attribute might give additional metadata (you can use the [`rel` values listed in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), or the [registered `rel` values in the microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions)), depending on the content/context.

### Which attributes?

Have a look at the [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#global-attributes).

The `class` attribute would be used if you'd like to use [microformats](http://microformats.org/). You could of course use other `class` names, but they would only be useful for yourself (documentation, CSS, JS) or other people that read your markup (documentation, scraping).

For entity names like person/company names you probably want to use the `translate` attribute with the `no` keyword, because such names should not be translated.

The `title` might give additional information (note that it has special semantics for `dfn`/`abbr`), but don't rely on it for important information.

Use `lang` if the entity names are in a foreign language.

### How to annotate the content with meaning?

There are three popular choices, which can also be used together (see [this answer (the "third step")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869163/1591669) for a short summary of the differences):

- microformats
- RDFa
- microdata

You may need additional elements; if so, use `span`.