# HTML5 semantic markup for blog post tags and categories

Tags: xml, html, metadata, schema.org

Many blogs use the concept of "tags" and "categories" to add metadata to a post. What is the best practice for semantic markup for this information, such that a machine reading the blog post could easily identify the tags?

Currently I add `"tag"` to the `rel` attribute on the link, e.g.

```
<a rel="tag" class="tag" href="/tags.html#site-configuration">#site-configuration</a>
```

I suppose one could use Dublin Core's html format for keyword:

```
<meta name = "DC.Subject"
          content = "site-configuration">
```

and add this to the page header, or can meta tags go in the body? Is one or the other preferable, or some entirely different option?

Is there a better strategy in terms of providing precise and standardized definitions for content?

Is HTML5 a reasonable choice if I want to be so picky about metadata, or should I be using an XML doctype?

What are the pros and cons of the different approaches?

Comment: `<meta name="keyword" content="site-configuration">` might be preferable, since I don't think the DC.Subject is valid html5.  Not sure what the right attributes would be for "categories", (i.e. there is no `rel="category"` attribute in the html5 standard(?))

Comment: XHTML5 will be advantageous when you use grddl or xslt as is often the case with semantically rich content.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **first step** would be to get/use the plain HTML semantically right. In case of (X)HTML5 you should build an appropriate outline using the sectioning content elements `section`, `article`, `aside` and `nav`, and use `header` and `footer` to separate the metadata content from the main content; also think of inline-level semantics like `time` (publication date), `dfn` (definitions), `abbr` (abbreviations/acronyms) etc. And make use of `meta`-`name` and `rel` values that are defined in the spec.

The **second step** would be to make use of metadata attribute values that are not defined in the specification, but are registered at specified places (so they are valid to use), like [`name` keywords for `meta` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) and [`rel` values for `a`/`area`/`link` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19428907/1591669).

The **third step** would be to enhance the markup with semantic, machine-readable annotations. There are [three common ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669):

- Microformats (using pre-defined `class` and `rel` values)
- RDFa (using attributes and URIs)
- Microdata (using attributes and URIs)

RDFa and Microdata are similar (both extensible and rather complex), while Microformats is simpler (but not so expressive/extensible). I wrote a [short answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/166669/63183) over at Programmers about the differences, and more detailed answer about the [differences between Microdata and RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).

In the case of RDFa or Microdata, your main job would be to find vocabularies/ontologies that are able to describe/classify your content. Such vocabularies can be created by everyone (you could even create one yourself), but it's often advisable to use well-known/popular ones, for example so that search engines can make use of your annotations (popular example: [Schema.org](http://schema.org/)).

In the case of Microformats, you'd  have to find a Microformat (on the [wiki at microformats.org](http://microformats.org/wiki/)) that suits your needs. If there is none for your case, you could propose a new Microformat (but that would take some time until it gets "accepted", if at all).

---

> Is HTML5 a reasonable choice if I want to be so picky about metadata, or should I be using an XML doctype?

You could also use XHTML5, if you need/want XML support. If you "only" use the (X)HTML defined in the specification and no additional XML schemas/vocabularies, it won't matter from a semantic perspective if you use HTML(5) or XHTML(5).

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Sounds like using a standard "class" attribute on an html tag (such as a link) is an example of a "microformat".  Is that true of using the "rel" attribute as well? The wiki you link defines [`rel="tag"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag) and [`rel="category"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-category) as "microformats" too.  Are the HTML5 tags like <header> and <footer> considered microformats?  Seems like they have a lot more strongly typed meaning than something like `<p class="vcard"> does, even though there's no explicit namespace

Comment: In particular, is there any advantage between defining a keyword using the HTML5 standard `<meta name="keyword" content="my-keyword">` vs the Dublin Core `<meta name="DC.Subject" content="my-keyword">` vs whatever the RDFa way to say that would be?

Comment: @cboettig: Yes, some microformats also use `rel` values (I added it to my answer). Note that it's only called "microformat", if it's specified in the wiki of microformats.org. So all `class`/`rel` values defined in other places are not microformats. Also note that the `rel` value "`tag`" is defined in HTML5 *and* also in microformats - and the definitions slightly differ. HTML elements (like `footer`) can never be microformats. microformats defines a way to "classify" the content of HTML elements with the help of these predefined values for the `class`/`rel` attributes. It's only a convention.

Comment: @cboettig: The definitions of `keywords` (in the HTML5 spec) and `dcterms.subject` (at WHATWG wiki resp. Dublin Core) *might* be different. You have to read carefully how they are defined. Of course it might be possible that they are the same. Also note that agents like search engines, bots, software etc. might only know one of possibly equivalent ways (e.g. a Dublin Core parser might only look for `dcterms.subject` but not for `keywords` etc.).