# In HTML5, what tag should I use for tags?

Tags: html, standards

I'm creating a template for my blog and decided that it should be HTML5 compliant. I don't know what tag I need to use for, well, tags on my blog. (e.g. #personal, #technology, #cooking, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 semantic markup for blog post tags and categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866008/html5-semantic-markup-for-blog-post-tags-and-categories)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [microformats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microformats). Microformats are a specific way of writing html tags so that they carry additional semantic meaning.

Benefits include

- They can help search engines exact out meaningful information out of a web page
- They use existing html tags
- In some cases they reuse existing html attributes
- In some cases they add additional "non-standard" html attributes

Drawbacks include

- Because they are not standardized, there is no guarantee that a particular format is reasonable.
- There can also be multiple competing microformats
- Even if you create the microformat, there is no guarantee it will be readable by anyone or anything
- They may cause web pages to fail validation

More details can be found at http://microformats.org

And of course http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat#Specific_microformats