# In HTML, how do I link to another 'instance' of 'this' document?

Tags: html, hyperlink, metadata

I want to do this for metadata purposes, rather than something that would explicitly displayed . So, for example, say my current document, Page A, is linked to from Page B e.g. a 'related article' in its sidebar. What link relation, or other markup, should I use in Page A to indicate this 'reverse linking' relationship?

Comment: Which effects do you expect or hope the link to have?

Comment: Hi @Jukka. None whatsoever, other than to act as metadata storage for separate processing.

Comment: Then isn’t it completely up to you, as long as you *don’t* use any attribute with a defined meaning?

Comment: I'm hoping there's an existing mechanism to do this very kind of thing. But, if not, sure I'll just make up my own link rel or use a data- attribute on HTML/BODY.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [rel attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp).

I would suggest you in order to accomplish what you wrote, use `rel="next"`, respectively `rel="prev"` inside an anchor tag

Comment: link rel="..." is definitely the closest I've got. I'm not sure 'next' is appropriate though; it would seem to be for, for example, a subsequent chapter of a book

Answer (score 1):

The `rel` attribute (which can be used on `link`, `a` and `area` elements) specifies the link relationship type.

In HTML5, you may only use the following `rel` values:

- [link types defined in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)
- link types [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types) in the Microformats wiki on the page http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions

If there is an appropriate link type depends on the specific relationship between your Page A and Page B. You only wrote "related article", but I don’t think that there would be a corresponding link type for such a general relation. I’d guess that all links on a page without a specific link type can be understood as "related".

You shouldn’t use `next`/`prev` unless your pages A and B are "[part of a sequence](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-next)".

If you don’t find appropriate link types, you may use [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) and/or [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) and look for a suitable vocabulary. For example schema.org’s [`http://schema.org/WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) specifies the [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink) property:

> A link related to this web page, for example to other related web pages.

It could look like (using RDFa Lite here):

```
<!-- on page B -->
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="WebPage">
  <a href="/article-a" property="relatedLink">Article A</a>
</div>
```